# SSRS custom assembly: build error add netstandard

Tags: c#, reporting-services, .net-assembly, .net-standard

I have a report using SQL on Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. I have a custom library assembly I am using which is to generate a barcode as an image from a field of data.
The assembly needs the DLL file and the Systems.Drawing assembly. I added both of these in and inputted some code:

```
Public Function Convert(Text As String) As Byte()
       Dim b As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    '   Dim bar As New BarcodeLib.Barcode
       bar.Alignment = BarcodeLib.AlignmentPositions.TOPCENTER
       bar.IncludeLabel = False
       bar.RotateFlipType = Drawing.RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone
       b = bar.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE39Extended, Text, 400, 30)
       Dim bitmapData As Byte() = Nothing
       Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
           b.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
           bitmapData = ms.ToArray()
       End Using
       Return bitmapData
   End Function
```

Please Note: the Bar is a reference name for the class

When I try to preview or build the report with or without using the barcode generation it fails.
The error is:

[rsCompilerErrorInCode] There is an error on line 3 of custom code [VC30007] Referene required to assmebly netstandard .... containing the base class System.Enum Add one to your project.

[rsCompilerErrorInClassInstanceDeclaration] Reference required to assembly netstandard, containing bade class System.Object add one to your project.

As far as I was aware you can't just add these as SSRS doesn't seem to have any NuGet or package support to allow me to do such a thing.

I have this barcode dll listed in practically all possible locations, on the server, my program files, MSbuild, Reporting Services bin folder on server, IDE public and private.
I did try loading from the MSBuild only to get assembly reference doesn't match the assembly manifest version. Even though they're the same.
I did try editing the code in C# to include the  for netstandard even though its connected via nuget on this project.

I'm expecting the image to convert using the =Code.Convert(*TEXT*) or =Code.Convert(databasefield) but it doesn't get this far. Even with no images or references to the code itself the build errors generate first.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this same error, with this exact same library, BarcodeStandard.dll. I tested with a 'hello world' .Net Standard lib for my own sanity and it seems SSRS does not support .Net Standard libraries. The equivalent 'hello world' library, in .Net Framework 4.6.2 worked without any problems on the server.

My solution was to rewrite the BarcodeStandard library in .Net Framework 4.6.2; this solution works for us when deployed on the server. It still doesn't work when previewing the report in Visual Studio 2019, but that's a minor issue.

Edit: we had the 'Could not load file or assembly' error when previewing in VS2019 or trying to deploy/run the report on the SSRS server, but not during build. 
Also, don't forget to add the reference to System.Drawing v4.0.0.0 in your report - it's required for the Barcode lib.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, at some point, the developer changed references to `.NET Standard` and I as well was unable to find a way to reference this in the report. Good idea by `@Fgaudet` to rewrite it with `.NET Frameword 4.6.2` for use in `SSRS`.
In the past I used the older version of `BarcodeLib - 2.2.5`, which worked fine with `System.Drawing v2.0.0.0` reference only.

Btw. if you are unable to preview report in VS2019, try to put the .dll into

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\

as well as

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS\

Comment: Hmm... so I checked older versions on GitHub, but even 2.2.5 references .netstandard. Probably I've rewritten it too in the past, but I forgot about it 

Comment: 1.3.0 is the last version before it was moved to .net standard 2 just before the major version change to 2.x. 1.3.0 works at least on SSRS 2017